# Wordpress Plugin to view member specific form data

Tags: wordpress

In the world of WP, I have been thrown, kicking and screaming.
I need help but I don't know where to get it, and this community has been vary helpful on programming questions, I hope I can get some guidance.

I have a members site - but there is a public form which lets a non-member send a request to a member, specified by their (the members) email address.

So something like this

```
Name: (text)
Email: (text)
Inquire to email: (text)
Inquiry: (text area)
```

This form is submitted and stored...

I want the members who are logged in to see a list of inquires in their members area - based on the "Inquire to email" - it must match the members login email to show in their area.

Is there a plugin to do this - or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend or find a plugin, software library etc. [are off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you are looking for a code-based solution, this question is still off topic for being too broad. Take a look at this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/) to see what you need to include. After you do some research and and make a good attempt to do this yourself, if you still have problems you can come back with the necessary info so we can help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use MemberPress or any other member-like plugin, see this link:

https://alternativeto.net/software/memberpress/

But since this is a very specific feature, you'll have to link it to a form like CF7 (Contact Form 7) or Formidable (you can use hooks and actions to code that, is very easy job for a WordPress developer or you can search for it)

This way what you'll have to do is set up a member space and after that make a contact form that sends data to a custom post type or something that's only accessible by members,

That's what you need?